# I have a lot/much/far/a bit/any more interests in common with my sister

Tags: grammar

I have a lot/much/far/a bit/any more interests in common with my sister.

I have a lot/much/far/a bit/any more stuff in common with my sister.

Can we use ***all the adverbs used for comparative*** forms (far/any/no/much/very much better) with ***more*** in above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

There are a *lot* of options in your question - and not all are common English:

- I have **a lot** more interests...
  You'd only use this if someone said "Do you have a lot of interests in common with your wife/niece/mother?" The use of "more" means that it's a comparative. The better version though would be "I have many more interests in common with my sister [than my wife/niece/mother]."
- I have **much** more interests...
  This is not English. "I have much more interest in my sister" would be better in English - but not a good statement to make! It implies a different kind of interest...
- I have **far** more interests...
  Same as the first one.
- I have **a bit** more interests...
  This is also not English. The correct version here would be "a few", and then it would be similar to the first one.
- I have **any** more interests...
  This is also not English. The correct version here would be "no".

As for the "stuff" versions, all are pretty good except the last one. They are all comparative, but the last needs to replace "any" with "no" again.

The difference is that "stuff" is effectively uncountable. You don't count "stuffs", but you do count "interests". That changes which words you can use.